# Is there a way to make a SPGridView look like XSLTListViewWebPart?

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, spgridview

is there a possibility to make an SPGridView (or any other WebControl) look like an XSLTListViewWebPart?

I want to mimic a sharepoint list, but can't use a plain list, since i have calculated data which I can not figure out to expose with a classic list view.
The calculated data is an email-link the users displayName and some other lookup Values (I don't want to have same linked). Default filtering and grouping should be possible since, i need that.

So do I have to stick to SPGridView, do I have to use the XSLTListView or any other webpart/webcontrol or what is the approach for something like that?

Comment: I imagine it would be easier to figure out how to put that calculated data into a normal SharePoint field than to figure out how to mimic the standard list view. Of course you know your problem better than anyone.

Comment: You may totally be right, but i dont have any clue, how to load a user object to show his email-Address (for example). I have more "no clues" with that.